# How can I run my Perl script only if it wasn't loaded with require?

Tags: perl, require

I have a Perl script. If it was called direct from the command line, I want to run `sub main`.

If it was called using require, I want to do nothing and wait for the caller script to call `sub job` at it's leisure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a recommended Perl solution for code which needs to be runnable from a script as well as a perl module.

It's usually called "modulino", which can be used as Google or SO search term to find how-tos.

Here's one how-to with reference links:

[Perl script usable as a program and as a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395733/perl-script-usable-as-a-program-and-as-a-module/3395759#3395759)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect. It is so easy, I will be using it for testing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you should be splitting your script into a module and a front-end program. Then programs which want to use the functionality can load the module using `use` (or `require`, if you insist) and the stub program can do that and the call the `job` subroutine as well.

Comment: Yea, I just came here to close the question. It turns out there is not a use for the script anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
package Some::Module;

sub job { ... }

sub main { ... } 

if (!caller) {
     main(@ARGV);
}

1;
__END__

=head1 NAME

Some::Module - program, podpage, and module

....
```

That can now simultaneously be all of:

1. an executable script to be called from the command line as a program (which will call its `main()` function)
2. a module to `use` from elsewhere in  which case it just loads function definitions
3. a podpage you can run `pod2text` on

Is that what you were looking for?