# Detect if called through require or directly by command line

Tags: node.js, require

How can I detect whether my Node.JS file was called using SH:`node path-to-file` or JS:`require('path-to-file')`?

This is the Node.JS equivalent to my previous question in Perl: [How can I run my Perl script only if it wasn't loaded with require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004466/how-can-i-run-my-perl-script-only-if-it-wasnt-loaded-with-require)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js equivalent of python's if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981891/node-js-equivalent-of-pythons-if-name-main)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus That was fun. _That_ question is marked as a dupe, and sends you back here. This one isn't as old and the answers are effectively the same, so your guess on why that one lost the dupe war is as good as mine.

Comment: pondering the implication of when providing information becomes 'war'...

Answer (score 629, accepted):

```
if (require.main === module) {
    console.log('called directly');
} else {
    console.log('required as a module');
}
```

See documentation for this here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module

Comment: Is there any way to get around this? I have code (which I don't have control over) that does this, but I need to require() it and have it act as though it was called directly. Basically, I need to fool something that uses that test into thinking it was called directly.

Comment: @Kevin I don't know about doing this with `require()`, but you could maybe do it with either importing the file then running `eval` on it, or by running `require('child_process').exec('node the_file.js')`

Comment: When using ES modules with Node.js, you can use the [`es-main`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-main) package to check if a module was run directly.

Comment: I regret using ES modules. All the tutorials were written before they existed and there's so much stuff that doesn't work and now I have to install npm packages just so I can import useful functions from a script without executing the actual script??

Comment: @Kevin Is there a way to prevent somebody from getting around my check?  I have code that I don't want to ever get tricked into thinking it was called directly... Is there any way to prevent somebody from preventing me from tricking their code? When does it end?

Answer (score 109):

There is another, slightly shorter way (not outlined in the mentioned docs).

`var runningAsScript = !module.parent;`

I outlined more details about how this all works under the hood in [this blog post](http://thlorenz.com/blog/how-to-detect-if-a-nodejs-module-is-run-as-a-script/).

Comment: +1, I like this better, but I will hesitate before switching accepted answers. :)

Comment: As I indicated, the official way that is documented is the one @nicolaskruchten outlined. This is just an alternative, no need to switch accepted answer. Both work.

Comment: I had to use this rather than the documented way - the documented way works for eg. `node script.js` but not `cat script.js | node`. This way works for both.

Comment: Please note that `module.parent` is deprecated ([since v14.6.0, v12.19.0](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#moduleparent)) so you should avoid it.

Answer (score 31):

For those using ES Modules, solutions using `require.main`, `module.parent` and `__dirname`/`__filename` won’t work because they [aren’t available in ESM](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs).

Instead, you can use `import.meta.url` (requires Node 10.12+) to determine if the current file is being run directly (rather than imported by another file):

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

const pathToThisFile = resolve(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
const pathPassedToNode = resolve(process.argv[1])
const isThisFileBeingRunViaCLI = pathToThisFile.includes(pathPassedToNode)

// Note:
// - `resolve()` is used to handle symlinks
// - `includes()` is used to handle cases where the file extension was omitted
//   when passed to node
```

This works by

1. Converting the `import.meta.url` value (a file path like `file:///Users/username/foo/bar.js`) into a regular path, e.g. `/Users/username/foo/bar.js`
2. Comparing that path to the first argument of the current process. If the file was invoked using `node foo/bar.js` then the first argument will be `foo/bar.js`.

> **ESLint Note**: If ESLint doesn’t like the `import.meta.url` syntax then you’ll need to [update to ESLint `^7.2.0`](https://eslint.org/blog/2020/06/eslint-v7.2.0-released) and turn your `ecmaVersion` up to `11` (`2020`).

*More info: [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv), [`import.meta.url`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta_url)*

Comment: This breaks if your working directory is a symlink. E.g. on Mac OS, /tmp -> /private/tmp. If you cd /tmp and run a script there, meta.url = file:///private/tmp/..., while process.argv[1] = /tmp/... .

Comment: rather than checking `fileURLtoPath` directly, use the `path` module to compare the `resolve`d paths, so you don't run into symlink issues.

Comment: See also separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842738/if-name-main-equivalent-in-javascript-es6-modules

Comment: This however won't work if you tried invoking the file without the file extension from the CLI. Since the `node` command supports that, we can modify the last statement to `const isRunningDirectlyViaCLI = modulePath.includes(nodePath)`

Answer (score 14):

I was a little confused by the terminology used in the explanation(s). So I had to do a couple quick tests.

I found that these produce the same results:

```
var isCLI = !module.parent;
var isCLI = require.main === module;
```

And for the other confused people (and to answer the question directly):

```
var isCLI = require.main === module;
var wasRequired = !isCLI;
```

Answer (score 8):

I always find myself trying to recall how to write this goddamn code snippet, so I decided to create a simple module for it. It took me a bit to make it work since accessing caller's module info is not straightforward, but it was fun to see how it could be done.

So the idea is to call a module and ask it if the caller module is the main one. We have to figure out the module of the caller function. My first approach was a variation of the accepted answer:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return require.main === module.parent;
};
```

But that is not guaranteed to work. `module.parent` points to the module which *loaded* us into memory, not the one calling us. If it is the caller module that loaded this helper module into memory, we're good. But if it isn't, it won't work. So we need to try something else. My solution was to generate a stack trace and get the caller's module name from there:

```
module.exports = function () {
    // generate a stack trace
    const stack = (new Error()).stack;
    // the third line refers to our caller
    const stackLine = stack.split("\n")[2];
    // extract the module name from that line
    const callerModuleName = /\((.*):\d+:\d+\)$/.exec(stackLine)[1];

    return require.main.filename === callerModuleName;
};
```

Save this as `is-main-module.js` and now you can do:

```
const isMainModule = require("./is-main-module");

if (isMainModule()) {
    console.info("called directly");
} else {
    console.info("required as a module");
}
```

Which is easier to remember.

Comment: Very cool. I love it when common code snippets are abbreviated to a single name. Small adjustment: `return require.main /*this is undefined if we started node interactively*/ && require.main.filename === callerModuleName;`

Answer (score 7):

Try this if you are using ES6 modules:

```
if (process.mainModule.filename === __filename) {
  console.log('running as main module')
}
```

Comment: crap, my `process.mainModule` is `undefined`

Comment: GHOSHHHH, i need to check this in my .mjs file

Comment: with node14 `if (require.main?.filename === __filename) {...}`

Comment: __filename is deprecated in ES modules: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_module_exports_filename_dirname

See documentation for an alternative

Comment: Downvoting this as `process.mainModule` is `undefined`. The real answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66309132/575796

Comment: `process.mainModule` is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

First, let's define the problem better. My assumption is that what you are really looking for is whether your script *owns* `process.argv` (i.e. whether your script is responsible for processing `process.argv`). With this assumption in mind, the code and tests below are accurate.

`module.parent` works excellently, but it is deprecated for good reasons (a module might have multiple parents, in which case `module.parent` only represents the first parent), so use the following future-proof condition to cover all cases:

```
if (
  typeof process === 'object' && process && process.argv
   && (
    (
      typeof module === 'object' && module
       && (
        !module.parent
         || require.main === module
         || (process.mainModule && process.mainModule.filename === __filename)
         || (__filename === "[stdin]" && __dirname === ".")
       )
    )
    || (
      typeof document === "object"
      && (function() {
       var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
       try { // in case we are in a special environment without path
         var normalize = require("path").normalize;
         for (var i=0,len=scripts.length|0; i < len; i=i+1|0)
           if (normalize(scripts[i].src.replace(/^file:/i,"")) === __filename)
             return true;
       } catch(e) {}
      })()
    )
   )
) {
    // this module is top-level and invoked directly by the CLI
    console.log("Invoked from CLI");
} else {
    console.log("Not invoked from CLI");
}
```

It works correctly in all of the scripts in all of the following cases and never throws any errors<sup>†</sup>:

- Requiring the script (e.x. `require('./main.js')`)
- Directly invoking the script (e.x. `nodejs cli.js`)
- Preloading another script (e.x. `nodejs -r main.js cli.js`)
- Piping into node CLI (e.x. `cat cli.js | nodejs`)
- Piping with preloading (e.x. `cat cli.js | nodejs -r main.js`)
- In workers (e.x. `new Worker('./worker.js')`)
- In `eval`ed workers (e.x. `new Worker('if (<test for CLI>) ...', {eval: true})`)
- Inside ES6 modules (e.x. `nodejs --experimental-modules cli-es6.js`)
- Modules with preload (e.x. `nodejs --experimental-modules -r main-es6.js cli-es6.js`)
- Piped ES6 modules (e.x. `cat cli-es6.js | nodejs --experimental-modules`)
- Pipe+preload module (e.x. `cat cli-es6.js | nodejs --experimental-modules -r main-es6.js`)
- In the browser (in which case, CLI is false because there is no `process.argv`)
- In mixed browser+server environments (e.x. ElectronJS, in which case both inline scripts and all modules loaded via `<script>` tags are considered CLI)

The only case where is does not work is when you preload the top-level script (e.x. `nodejs -r cli.js cli.js`). This problem cannot be solved by piping (e.x. `cat cli.js | nodejs -r cli.js`) because that executes the script twice (once as a required module and once as top-level). I do not believe there is any possible fix for this because there is no way to know what the main script will be from inside a preloaded script.

<sup>†</sup> Theoretically, errors might be thrown from inside of a getter for an object (e.x. if someone were crazy enough to do `Object.defineProperty(globalThis, "process", { get(){throw 0} });`), however this will never happen under default circumstances for the properties used in the code snippet in any environment.

Comment: This doesn't work for es modules (where neither `module` or `document` are defined globals). You can verify this in a dir with a `"type": "module"` package.json, a `test.js` file that has your code, and then running `node test.js`. It will incorrectly report `Not invoked from CLI`.

Answer (score 2):

> > *How can I detect whether my node.js file was called directly from console (windows and unix systems) or loaded using the ESM module import ( `import {foo} from 'bar.js'`)*
>
> Such functionality is not exposed. For the moment you should separate your cli and library logic into separate files.

Answer from node.js core contributor **devsnek** replying to [nodejs/help/issues/2420](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2420#issuecomment-575044606)

It's the right answer in my point of view