# Detect if NODE.JS script is called direct via bash (unix) / cmd (windows) or imported (ESM module loader)

Tags: node.js

How can I detect whether my node.js file was called directly from console (windows and unix systems) or loaded using the ESM module import (`import {foo} from 'bar.js'`)

The question was already answered for regular node.js files ([Detect if called through require or directly by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398196/detect-if-called-through-require-or-directly-by-command-line)) but since `require` is not available in .mjs files with `--experimental-modules` turned on, I am in need of a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js does not currently expose that information to es modules, and it is not certain whether it ever will[0]. I'd say the safest option for now is to put your CLI logic into a separate file.

0: https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/274