# Can i import a module without execute it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to import a module into another and run it only when called?

Actually i am importing like this.

```
import {getData, paginacao} from './restCountries.js'
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). You might revise to ask about what you're actually trying to accomplish instead.

Comment: Thanks for the alert, I gonna read this to make better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Importing a module always causes its initialisation code to run - otherwise there wouldn't be any values that you can use.

If there's code in a module that you don't want to run immediately, put it into a function and export that.

Answer (score 1):

there is a way to detect if your module is being imported or called directly and execute different parts of the file.

This has been answerred in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6398335/763962)

```
if (require.main === module) {
    console.log('called directly');
} else {
    console.log('required as a module');
}
```