# Why is the Switch module deprecated in Perl?

Tags: perl, module, switch-statement

Why was the [Switch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Switch) module [deprecated in Perl 5.12](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#Deprecated_Modules)?

I know that a `switch`/`case` be made with `elsif`, but I don't like that very much.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perl 5.10 introduced [a real switch called given-when](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5100delta#Switch_and_Smart_Match_operator)

The old [Switch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Switch) used [source filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785852/why-are-perl-source-filters-bad-and-when-is-it-ok-to-use-them) and had other [limitations](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Switch#LIMITATIONS).

Comment: I was rather hoping that Perl would ditch the `given`/`when` keywords and use something more similar other languages... like `switch`/`case`.  I would say that those aren't "Huffman coded" (Larry's phrase from Perl 6 Apocalypse 3) but they're the same length...

Comment: @OMG, I mostly work in Perl 5.8 but IIRC you can use a `for`/`when` construct.  `for`/`case` would seem weird.

Comment: @OMG Perl's `given`, and `when` operators don't really behave anything like other language's `switch`/`case` so they are given different names.

Comment: Further, Switch was removed from the core in Perl 5.14.

Comment: Since then, [The smartmatch family of features are now experimental](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#The_smartmatch_family_of_features_are_now_experimental) and issue warnings since 5.18.0. I guess we're stuck with good-old `for`, `if`, `elsif` and `else`.

Comment: just want to note that good to use something like HASH with CODEREFs. stackoverflow.com/a/46077110/1336858

Answer (score 18):

The original [Switch](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Switch) uses a source filter to do its work, and that's often a bad idea. Essentially, it pre-processes your literal source to create new code before perl compiles it. The module was never really intended to be heavily used, and it was more of a proof of concept to figure out what a real Perl feature could look like.

Perl 5.10 added the `given-when` construct to do what most people want from a `switch-case`, but it does quite a bit more. [Learning Perl, 5th Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113) devotes an entire chapter to it along with smart matching. However, in *Learning Perl* 7th Edition we removed that chapter since smart-matching is experimental as of v5.18.

You can't make a Perl `given-when` with the `if-elsif-else` constructs. `given-when` lets you  execute multiple blocks and well as add interstitial code. With `if-elsif-else` you execute exactly one branch.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Switch is not deprecated. It's *inclusion in core* was deprecated in 5.12. All that means is that while Switch was bundled with Perl 5.8 and 5.10, it isn't bundled in Perl 5.14 and newer. It does NOT mean people should stop using the module. The module may still be installed from CPAN separately from `perl`.

Mind you, many including myself advise others to avoid using Switch, but that's independent of its deprecation from core, and it far predates 5.12. Using Switch can lead to very odd and hard to debug errors because it modifies your code before Perl sees it, all while providing minimal benefit if any at all.

For that reason, and because Perl started offering a native alternative (`given`-`when`), it was decided that Switch would no longer be bundled with `perl`.

Unfortunately, `given`-`when` has problems, and was retroactively marked as experimental in 5.18. It isn't safe to use these as they [*will*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16927024/589924) be changed in a backwards-incompatible manner (or maybe removed) in the future.