# Missing switch.pm - Active Perl x64/windows

Tags: perl, activeperl

I have installed Active Perl (v5.14.2, 64-bit, for Windows) and my code containing `use Switch;` started to fail with the error `Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at myfilename.pl line 3.`.

Copying `switch.pm` over from an older 32-bit installation fixed the problem, but I don't understand it. Has `switch.pm` been deprecated in the meantime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the Switch module deprecated in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630547/why-is-the-switch-module-deprecated-in-perl)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was replaced with [given/when](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements):

> Starting from Perl 5.10, you can say
>
> ```
> use feature "switch";
> ```
>
> which enables a switch feature that is closely based on the Perl 6 proposal.

See also [Deprecations in perl5101delta](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5101delta#Deprecations):

> The following items are now deprecated.
>
> Switch is buggy and should be avoided. From perl 5.11.0 onwards, it is intended that any use of the core version of this module will emit a warning, and that the module will eventually be removed from the core (probably in perl 5.14.0).

If you have legacy code that uses Switch.pm, it's still [available on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Switch/).

Answer (score 6):

You can install the "Switch" package on a windows system at the command prompt with the command: `ppm install Switch`

Comment: Thanks and it works for ActivePerl 5.20.2.200 for windows x86 for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install "[Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)" it is aperl version + cpan module ;)