# Why switch doesn't work?

Tags: perl, switch-statement, mod-perl, perl-data-structures

This program throws an error. The problem is that I have to use `switch` `case`. How can I do this in Perl?

```
#use strict;
#use warnings;
my $input = print "Enter the number";
$input = <STDIN>;
switch($input){
    case "1" {print "UPC"}
    case "2" {print "ES"}
    case "3" {print "MS"}
    else {print "Enter the correct value"}
}
```

Comment: What does your title mean?

Comment: For future reference, it's generally helpful to state what error message you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import Switch to use it:

```
use Switch;
```

However, Switch has been [deprecated](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#Deprecated_Modules). See this question: [Why is the Switch module deprecated in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630547/why-is-the-switch-module-deprecated-in-perl)

Some alternatives (and their experimental status) are discussed here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements

In summary, if you're using Perl >5.10.1, you can use the following for a non-deprecated, non-experimental switch:

```
use v5.10.1;
for ($var) {
    when (/^abc/) { $abc = 1 }
    when (/^def/) { $def = 1 }
    when (/^xyz/) { $xyz = 1 }
    default { $nothing = 1 }
}
```

Comment: It's not deprecated, but it is experimental.

Answer (score 2):

[Perl's built in version of the case statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) is a little different:

```
use feature "switch";

given ($foo) {
        when (/^abc/) { $abc = 1; }
        when (/^def/) { $def = 1; }
        when (/^xyz/) { $xyz = 1; }
        default { $nothing = 1; }
    }
```

You can add a more traditional case statement with [`use Switch;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/Switch.html), but this is deprecated as RobEarl points out.

Also, *never* comment out `use strict; use warnings;` as an attempt to fix problems!