# switch vs. given vs. for-when vs. if-elsif-else in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement, switch-statement

In one of the last scripts I wrote, I needed a behavior similar to a switch statement behavior. A simple search of an equivalent in Perl led me to `use Switch`. At the beginning, all was fine and working, until everything just crashed with errors that are not very descriptive (it happened on a switch statement that had cases with regex, but strangely it didn't happen on other switch statements that are alike).

**EDIT:** the code that crashed was looking like this one:

```
switch ($var) {
    case /pattern1/ {...}
    case /pattern2/ {...}
    ...
    else {...}
}
```

That led me to abandon the use of `Switch.pm` and search for an alternative.

I found `given` and `for-when` and of course there's always the straightforward and somewhat naive `if-elsif-else`.

1. Why is `Switch.pm` so unstable?
2. It seems `given` and `for-when` have a similar structure, but I guess there's a difference (because both exist). What is it?
3. Is `if-elsif-else` significantly slower than the other options?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2630547/5830574

Comment: That answers my first question, thanks! It's also nice to know that `given` has more capabilities.

Comment: `given` used to set lexical `$_`, but that doesn't exist anymore. /// `given`'s expression is evaluated in scalar context, whereas `for` loops over the returned scalars. /// Something tells me there's a difference in the flow-control keywords allowed in `given` vs `for`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl's `when` and smart-matching are experimental, and they [won't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16927024/589924) become features without backward-incompatible changes. You should not use these.

[Switch.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Switch) is a source filter, so it can produce incorrect error message when something's wrong. It also suffers from the same problems as smart-matching. You should not use this.

So, of the options you listed, only one is viable, and it's not any slower at all!

Comment: Great answer. Instinct told me `if-elsif-else` is slower than dedicated statements and modules for case handling, so if it's not slower at all, why even create these modules in the first place?

Comment: It's just syntax. For example, `given ($x) { when ([qw( a b c )]) { ... } when ([qw( d e f )]) { ... } ... }` vs `if (grep { $x eq $_ } qw( a b c )) { ... } elsif (grep { $x eq $_ } qw( d e f )) { ... }  ...`