# How to group cases within a switch statement in Perl

Tags: string, perl, switch-statement

Given a code

```
use Switch;

my $var1x = "one";

switch ($var1x) {
    case "one" { print "Why so small?\n"}
    case "two" { print "Why so small?\n"}
    case "three" { print "That is ok.\n"}
    case "four"  { print "That is ok.\n"}
}
```

I would like to group the implementation of similar cases. Any recommendations how to write it in Perl properly?

Comment: `case qr/^one|two\z/` or `case [qw(one two)]` => https://metacpan.org/pod/Switch#SYNOPSIS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't use old, slow `Switch` module.

Usually it is resolved by CODEREF hashes.

```
my $var1x = "one";

my $is_ok     = sub { print "That is ok.\n"};
my $why_small = sub { print "Why so small?\n" };

my %switch = (
    one   => $why_small,
    two   => $why_small,
    three => $is_ok,
    four  => $is_ok,
    ten   => sub { print "Unbelievable!\n"; },
);

$switch{$var1x}->();
```